# Pointer change its address after exiting a recursive function

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion

I have a binary search tree in which I want to get the adress of a specific node using preorder traversal (ROOT, LEFT, RIGHT) and then do something with it.

The recursive function works, but when it quits the pointer to the node change back to NULL.

```
void rlr(Node * x,Node * z)
{
    if (x != NULL)
    {
        if (a condition)
        {
            z = x;
        }
        rlr(x->get_left(),z);
        rlr(x->get_right(),z);
    }
}

void main()
{
....
Node * z = NULL;
rlr(root,z);
while(z!=NULL)
....
}
```

More exactly in rlr function if a condition is true z points to a node and it should point at that node, but when it quits the function, z points back to NULL instead pointing to that specific node.

Comment: You have two different variables named z. Which one are you assigning to?

Comment: Parameters are passed by value in C++.

Comment: If you really want to modify the passed in parameter you need to pass by reference though there are often better options available - e.g.: in this case you could just `return` the desired pointer (also you shouldn't use `NULL` and prefer smart pointers over raw pointers)

Comment: There's nothing special about pointers. Assigning to a pointer parameter has as little effect outside the function as it would have on an `int` or `std::string`.

Comment: @UnholySheep I can't use return because there are some cases when it will not find anything and in that case I want to have my pointer pointed to NULL.I will read about smart pointers.

Comment: You can also return `NULL` (or preferably `nullptr`) from a function, this is in fact often used to indicate that the function did not succeed (in finding a valid object)

Comment: I know what are you saying but how could I know when to return nullptr ?I don't know when it gets to the end of tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `z` in the main function is not modified. Add a level of indirection to make it works:

```
void rlr(Node * x,Node ** z)
{
    if (x != NULL)
    {
        if (a condition)
        {
            *z = x;
        }
        rlr(x->get_left(),z);
        rlr(x->get_right(),z);
    }
}

void main()
{
....
Node * z = NULL;
rlr(root,&z);
while(z!=NULL)
....
}
```

That should make it. Please look at
`Node** z` instead of `Node* z` in the function parameter,
`*z` instead of `z` in the assignement
`&z` in the function call instead of `z`

Comment: Why would you use a pointer to a pointer for this? Also `void main()` is non-standard

Comment: I thought if I am working with memory and I don't need another level of indirection, I was very close earlier but not enough.Thanks.I thought I knew how to work with pointers but it seems that I have to recap.

Comment: A pointer-to-a-pointer will work, but that is the C way of doing it. In C++, prefer using a reference-to-pointer instead: `void rlr(Node* x, Node* &z) { ... z = x; ... } int main() { ... rlr(root, z); ... }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I agree, that will also make the z parameter not optional (cannot be NULL as you can do in my example). But for the sake or reading and "learning" I thought it was better to highlight the change in the indirection level making an explicit use of a pointer-to-a-pointer.